# Using awk to mix two files

Tags: linux, awk

I have two tab delimited files

`file1.txt`

```
field1
field2
field3
```

`file2.txt`

```
field1   value f11
field1   value f12
field1   value f13
field2   value f21
field2   value f22
field2   value f23
field3   value f31
```

I want the output

```
field1   value f11, value f12 , valuef13
field2   value f21, value f22 , valuef23
field3   value f31
```

I am trying this

```
awk -F"\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$1] = $1;next} { print a[$1]  }' file1.txt file2.txt
```

and it is coming as empty

If filds are in file1 and not in file2 then that should comas blank

UPDATE:

This is my output from my terminal

```
    ubuntu@ubuntu:/mnt/coding/awk$ cat f1.txt 
    field1
    field2
    field3
    field9

    ubuntu@ubuntu:/mnt/coding/awk$ cat f2.txt 
    field1  value f11
    field1  value f12
    field1  value f13
    field2  value f21
    field2  value f22
    field2  value f23
    field3  value f31

    ubuntu@ubuntu:/mnt/coding/awk$ awk -F"\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$1] = a[$1]", "$2;next}{gsub("^,","",a[$1]);print $1"\t"a[$1]}' f2.txt f1.txt
    field1  
    field2  
    field3  
    field9  

    ubuntu@ubuntu:/mnt/coding/awk$ awk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.8
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2010 Free Software Foundation.
```

UPDATE 2:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/mnt/coding/awk$ od -xcb f1.txt
0000000    6966    6c65    3164    660a    6569    646c    0a32    6966
          f   i   e   l   d   1  \n   f   i   e   l   d   2  \n   f   i
        146 151 145 154 144 061 012 146 151 145 154 144 062 012 146 151
0000020    6c65    3364    660a    6569    646c    0a39    000a
          e   l   d   3  \n   f   i   e   l   d   9  \n  \n
        145 154 144 063 012 146 151 145 154 144 071 012 012
0000035
ubuntu@ubuntu:/mnt/coding/awk$ od -xcb f2.txt
0000000    6966    6c65    3164    2020    6176    756c    2065    3166
          f   i   e   l   d   1           v   a   l   u   e       f   1
        146 151 145 154 144 061 040 040 166 141 154 165 145 040 146 061
0000020    0a31    6966    6c65    3164    2020    6176    756c    2065
          1  \n   f   i   e   l   d   1           v   a   l   u   e    
        061 012 146 151 145 154 144 061 040 040 166 141 154 165 145 040
0000040    3166    0a32    6966    6c65    3164    2020    6176    756c
          f   1   2  \n   f   i   e   l   d   1           v   a   l   u
        146 061 062 012 146 151 145 154 144 061 040 040 166 141 154 165
0000060    2065    3166    0a33    6966    6c65    3264    2020    6176
          e       f   1   3  \n   f   i   e   l   d   2           v   a
        145 040 146 061 063 012 146 151 145 154 144 062 040 040 166 141
0000100    756c    2065    3266    0a31    6966    6c65    3264    2020
          l   u   e       f   2   1  \n   f   i   e   l   d   2        
        154 165 145 040 146 062 061 012 146 151 145 154 144 062 040 040
0000120    6176    756c    2065    3266    0a32    6966    6c65    3264
          v   a   l   u   e       f   2   2  \n   f   i   e   l   d   2
        166 141 154 165 145 040 146 062 062 012 146 151 145 154 144 062
0000140    2020    6176    756c    2065    3266    0a33    6966    6c65
                  v   a   l   u   e       f   2   3  \n   f   i   e   l
        040 040 166 141 154 165 145 040 146 062 063 012 146 151 145 154
0000160    3364    2020    6176    756c    2065    3366    0a31    000a
          d   3           v   a   l   u   e       f   3   1  \n  \n
        144 063 040 040 166 141 154 165 145 040 146 063 061 012 012
0000177
ubuntu@ubuntu:/mnt/coding/awk$
```

Other:

```
awk -F"\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$1] = a[$1]", "$2; print "["$1"/"$2"]"; next}{gsub("^,","",a[$1]);print $1"\t"a[$1]}' f2.txt f1.txt
[field1  value f11/]
[field1  value f12/]
[field1  value f13/]
[field2  value f21/]
[field2  value f22/]
[field2  value f23/]
[field3  value f31/]
[/]
field1  
field2  
field3  
field9
```

Comment: That script won't do what you want but neither will it produce NO output given those 2 input files so there must be something about the input files that you misunderstand or aren't telling us.

Comment: What is the purpose of `file1.txt`? It doesn't seem to actually contribute anything.

Comment: file1 may have fields which are not in file2. i want those as empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's *one* possible solution:

```
NR==FNR{a[$1]=a[$1]", "$2;next}{gsub("^,","",a[$1]);print $1"\t"a[$1]}
```

This works by storing the keys and values in `file2` first, then processing file1 to output them. The following (slightly formatted) transcript shows this in action:

```
pax> cat file1.txt

field1
field2
field3
field9

pax> cat file2.txt

field1  value f11
field1  value f12
field1  value f13
field2  value f21
field2  value f22
field2  value f23
field3  value f31

pax> awk -F"\t" 'NR == FNR{
...>                 a[$1] = a[$1]", "$2;
...>                 next
...>             }
...>             {
...>                 gsub ("^,", "", a[$1]);
...>                 print $1"\t"a[$1]
...>             }' file2.txt file1.txt 

field1   value f11, value f12, value f13
field2   value f21, value f22, value f23
field3   value f31
field9
```

---

Based on your update where I suggested you use the `sed` command `print "["$1"/"$2"]"` and you got:

```
[field1  value f11/]
[field1  value f12/]
[field1  value f13/]
[field2  value f21/]
[field2  value f22/]
[field2  value f23/]
[field3  value f31/]
```

that indicates that those fields are *not* tab-separated. This is also confirmed by the output of the `od` command where you can clearly see th e `2020` two-space sequence.

You need to sort that out or the commands won't work with `-F"\t"`. For example, if I replace each tab in my `file2.txt` with a space, I see what you're seeing:

```
pax> awk -F"\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$1] = a[$1]", "$2;next}
...>   {gsub("^, ","",a[$1]);print $1"\t"a[$1]}' file2.txt file1.txt 
field1  
field2  
field3  
field9
```

So, you need to make a decision, either:

- modify the file so that it *is* tab-separated; or
- modify the `awk` options to work with the *actual* file format.

Given you have spaces elsewhere on the line, the first option is probably the easiest. To modify the file to replace the first group of spaces on each line with a tab, you can use:

```
sed 's/  */\t/' file2.txt >file2a.txt
mv file2a.txt file2.txt                 # once you're happy.
```

(or use the `-i` inplace editing option of GNU `sed`).

Comment: i don't know whats wrong i tried your thing and i get this `field1
field2
field3
        `

Comment: @user1865341, you need to re-examine your input files to ensure they meet the spec (eg, `od -xcb file2.txt`). You also need to check that you're using a decent `awk` implementation (eg, `awk --version`). FWIW, I'm running `GNU Awk 3.1.7`.

Comment: I have updated the question with my output , can you have a look what can be wrong

Comment: @user1865341, show the output of `od -xcb fX.txt` where X is 1 and 2. Also in the `NR==FNR` code, put print "["$1"/"$2"]";` as the first statement and see what comes out.

Comment: @user1865341, see my answer update. I don't thing that file _is_ tab separated.

Comment: How can make the file tab separated. Also ican't use default awk separator because i had many spaces in second column of ethe file

Comment: @user1865341, you need to modify the file itself to get tabs in there. You can edit it, or pass it through something like `sed 's/  */\t/'`  or any number of other ways. Try `sed 's/  */\t/' file2.txt >file3.txt` to replace the first multi-space section with a tab, and then use `file3` (or `mv file3.txt file2.txt` once you're satisfied it worked okay).

Answer (score 0):

Using other tools instead of awk (and assuming there's a tab to separate fields from values in file2):

```
for f in `cat /tmp/file1.txt`; do grep $f /tmp/file2.txt | cut -f2- | paste -s -d, | sed "s/^/$f\t/g" ; done
```

(I'd have posted this as a comment but it doesn't seem to be possible to escape backticks in comments)

Comment: You can get back ticks into comments by using, for example, two or more back ticks together, then the code you want: ``var=`ls` `` if you see what I mean.  You can't have a space between the opening back ticks and the text that follows.